# Static initialization in c++ and thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, thread-safety

Static initialization of class instances is not thread-safe. The code below is an example of what not to do :

```
extern int computesomething();

class cachedcomputation
{
public:
    cachedcomputation()
    {
        result = computesomething();
    }

    int result;
};

void usecached()
{
    static cachedcomputation c;

    // use of c.result - may break
}
```

However, would the code below be thread-safe ? (Ignoring the ugliness of the solution) When or why would it break ?

```
extern int computesomething();

class cachedcomputation
{
public:
    cachedcomputation()
    {
    if(0==InterlockedCompareExchange(&mutex, 1, 0))
    {
        // first thread
            result = computesomething();
        InterlockedExchange(&mutex, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        // other thread - spinlock until mutex==2
        while(2!=InterlockedCompareExchange(&mutex, 2, 2)){}
    }
    }

    int result;

private:
    long mutex;
};

void usecached()
{
    static cachedcomputation c;

    // use of c.result - ???
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

- initialize your "mutex"
- reset "mutex" at the end of if block: InterlockedExchange(&mutex, 0)
- optionally convert if-statement to while, so your code would block until "mutex" is unlocked

Comment: 1 - the static should set it to 0 by default ?
2&3 - I want the computesomething to be called only once. solution modified to take it into account and make it clearer

Comment: `long mutex` is not static itself, and is never assigned. `cachedcomputation() : mutex(0)` is a clean way to initialize `mutex`.

Comment: @MichaelSh Why do you reset "mutex" to zero?

Comment: Reset is not required as `computesomething` is required to be called only once. Initialization of `mutex` to zero is still required, though.